# Каким способом можно реализовать такое состояние загрузки?

Tags: android, kotlin, loading

В приложении есть экран с профилем пользователя. Пока подгружаются данные с сервера, нужно показывать пользователю состояние загрузки с переливающейся полоской. Примерно также, как это реализовано в приложении ВКонтакте:

[image: Образец]

Как это реализовать? Есть какой-то готовый компонент или просто сделать фрейм с разметкой и прятать его после окончания загрузки? Но как тогда сделать переливающуюся анимацию? Не хотелось бы колхозить.

Comment: Посмотрите либу для shimmer эффекта от   корпорации зла Meta

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!